# How to know client interrupt request, when php is handling

Tags: php, mysql, request, client, interrupt-handling

I'm trying, handle my program when client turn off browser or tab.
while request php is not complete.

For example, i will save score to Database before browser or tab turn off

```
$i = 0;
$score = 0;
while($i++ < 100000){
    $score +=2;
}
$sql = "UPDATE games SET score=$score WHERE uid=123";
$conn = new Mysqli(params);
$conn->query($sql);
```

if current $i is 1000, request is handling and client turn off browser or tab. Therefore, below command is not handle.

```
$sql = "UPDATE games SET score=$score WHERE uid=123";
$conn = new Mysqli(params);
$conn->query($sql);
```

How to immediate, i can save current score to Database.

Answer (score 0):

The default PHP behavior is:

After a user closes the browser window/tab, the script will terminate if it either:

1. reaches its the **max_execution_timeout** setting (a PHP
   environment variable), or
2. attempts to output anything to the
   browser.

However, you can change this behavior by:

1. changing the **max_execution_timeout** setting to 0 (to allow for unlimited runtime) and
2. changing the **ignore_user_abort** setting (another PHP environment variable) to true.

See also:

[SO: excellent answer for a question just like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360303/640113)

[PHP manual: Connection Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)