# finish execution of the script via popen even if the browser tab closes

Tags: php, exec, popen

If I have this on my webpage :

```
$f = popen("/home/username/bin/something --json arg1 arg2", "rb");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== false) {
    $event = json_decode($line);
    // do something
}
fclose($f);
```

If the the browser closes unexpectedly, will the execution of `/home/username/bin/something` stop ?
I need it to be finished even if the browser tab closes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360303/3387716

Comment: Take a look at the `ignore_user_abort()` function php offers.